# Behavior of fundamental solution for parabolic equation on non compact complete riemannian manifold

Tags: operator-theory, parabolic-pde

Suppose that M is a complete noncompact Riemannian manifold. What is the necessary and sufficient condition that an operator on $L^{2}(M)$ comes from a smooth kernel that itself and all of the its derivatives decay at infinity?

This question can arise when one studies the behavior of the Green Function of a parabolic linear PDE on a complete noncompact Riemannian manifold. When the initial condition is in $L^{2}(M)$ then the solution is $H^{1}(M)$ or a better space. But if the initial condition is distribution like delta function of a point in the manifold, what one can say about the existence and uniqueness and the behavior of the solution?

For example for the Euclidean space, the fundamental solution of the heat equation is $exp(-|x|^{2}/4t) /(4 \pi t)^{n/2}$ that has very nice behavior at infinity.